# JAVA UDP Receive not working in different Network

Tags: java, networking, udp, udpclient

I made a little tool to receive/send certain UDP packets.
It works without problems in my home network, whether the packets come from this very PC, my Android phone or another PC in the Network.
But if I try to use it in the network it's supposed to be used, the receiving part stop working.

The Firewall is not the problem since I see the received UDP packets in Wireshark.
Here is the part of the code that's the problem (if it is caused by the code):

```
        static byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
        ..... //more code + sending part of the program 
        while (true){
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            //"buffer" 
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("Packet received!");

            // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
            String msg = new String(buffer, 0, receivePacket.getLength());
            System.out.println(receivePacket.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
                + msg);

            // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
           receivePacket.setLength(buffer.length);

           //irrelevant stuff....
             ....


        }
```

If I run the program in my home network and send a packet to my PC from anywhere I get this output:

"192.168.0.XXX: ContentsOfThePacket" and I can work with the msg string.
But in the other network nothing happens when `serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);` is reached, even though the excat same packet as on the home network is being received by the pc (confirmed via wireshark), so it doen't seems to be caused by the Firewall that is set up there.
Also the whole "sending packets to a certain pc in the network" part is working flawlessly...

Edit: I also ran the program on my Notebook now and it worked without problems, not matter who sends the packet (other pc, phone) and also no matter which interface I use to connect to the network (usb-ethernet adapter or wlan) (in the home network again), but with the notebook it also didn't work for the other network

Comment: what is the other network you are speaking about? is that similar to the one that you are already using? If its windows try to add an exception in the firewall rule for the port you are using and see.

Comment: the other network is something like this:                              server - monowall - switch - pc/notebook                            monowall/server are not the problem since I can see the packets I should receive from the server in wireshark.                                I also disabled the windows Firewall for everything and turned off my Bitdefender...

Comment: Can someone tell me: if the windows firewall "blocks" the packet, shouldn't it never apppear in wireshark? Or is it more like     cable > interface > wireshark > windows firewall,             so I can see the packet in wireshark even if the windows firewall blocks it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think wireshark might capture the packets though your firewall blocks. You need to understand where firewall works ( which layer of OSI stack), but wireshark can capture at most of the layers. you can just test it with iperf. Its a traffic generator. So run iperf at xxxx port and receive traffic from server. Block that port deliberately in firewall. See if wireshark can capture that traffic. If it does, you can rule out that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

No chance to give you a solution (would be guessing), but I recomment to isolate the problem by testing this scenario with netcat (if you are on unix or have cygwin available). Netcat has an UDP mode ( -u switch). If you can transfer your data with netcat, it is your program. If this fails, you need not debug further.

On receiving side:

```
nc -u -p <port>
```

On the sending side:

```
echo "Hello" | nc -u <host> <port>
```

Comment: I can receive/send the packets on the PC without problems, the device I'm sending them too acts accordingly and wiresharks says I'm sending/receiving everything I need for the program to work, even in the other Network. But somehow my program acts like there are no incoming UDP Packets (it should output any UDP Packet thatz is received)...